# Nasm: how to load a long double into the FPU from memory

Tags: c, nasm, fpu, long-double

I am writing a function in nasm that will be called from 32bit ansi C.

The function prototype in C looks like this:
`long double scalar(int n, long double *x)` 
Where x is a pointer to an array of `long doubles`.

The problem occurs when I try to load a single `long double` to the FPU:

```
    mov ecx, [esp+8] ; n
    mov eax, [esp+12] ; *x
    fld [eax] ; ERROR: operation size not specified
```

How should I specify the size? My C compiler uses 12 bytes for a long double, how to fit it into the 80 bits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify the size explicitely use the following form in NASM:

```
fld TWORD [eax] ; load 10 bytes from [eax]
```

As you pointed out, FPU stack registers are 80 bits wide. The C compiler chooses 12 bytes, because of the data alignment requirements of the stack frame.

Comment: in nasm the keyword is `tword`.

Comment: @JanOsch: Yeah, I wasn't sure between these two. Thank you,